# bug in aspnet_compiler?

Tags: aspnet-compiler

I have a solution with several web projects.

I have built each project into its own folder (there's about 10 projects):

```
/build/projA
/build/projB
/build/projC
```

If I call

```
aspnet_compiler -v / -p \"build/#{proj}\" merged/#{proj}
```

on each one in turn, everything is fine.

If I make all 10 calls to `aspnet_compiler` in parallel, I get assembly loading errors, saying the referenced assemblies are in use.

Is this a bug? Why would it be in use? It shouldn't be.

The assemblies that cant be loaded are in multiple projects, but each one has its own copy in its bin folder.

**Update:** it seems to occur (for some) of the assemblies that are references of references. Those loaded with complete binding information seem to work.

Here's a dump from one of the failed loadings from `fuslogvw`

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070020. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = andrew.bullock
LOG: DisplayName = Yahoo.Yui.Compressor
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Yahoo.Yui.Compressor | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/build/ProjA/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\build\ProjA\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\src_projects_proja\061ad2e7
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\src_projects_proja\061ad2e7
LOG: AppName = 627cc9a9
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\build\ProjA\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/src_projects_proja/061ad2e7/627cc9a9/Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/src_projects_proja/061ad2e7/627cc9a9/Yahoo.Yui.Compressor/Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/build/ProjA/bin/Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: E:\build\ProjA\bin\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80070020).
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80070020.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070020). Probing terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the `ClientBuildManager` directly, outside of `aspnet_compiler` there doesn't seem to be a problem, no idea why.

```
var parameter = new ClientBuildManagerParameter
    {
        PrecompilationFlags = PrecompilationFlags.ForceDebug
    };
var client = new ClientBuildManager("/", src, dest, parameter);
client.PrecompileApplication();
```